# How to subtract one record from another data frame in R

Tags: r

I have two data frame. One data frame has only 1 record and 3 columns. Another data frame has 6 rows and 3 columns.
Now I want to subtract data frame 1 values from data frame 2 values.

Sample data:

```
df1 = structure(list(col1 = 2L, col2 = 3L, col3 = 4L), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

df2 = structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L), col2 = c(1L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 7L), col3 = c(6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Final output should be like,

```
output = structure(list(col1 = c(-1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), col2 = c(-2L, 
-1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L), col3 = c(2L, 0L, -1L, 2L, 0L, 2L)), .Names =      c("col1","col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: check out `?data.table::fsetdiff`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `df2 - df1` directly you get

```
df2 - df1
```

> Error in Ops.data.frame(df2, df1) : 
>     ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

So let us make `df1` the same size as `df2` by repeating rows and then subtract

```
df2 - df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), nrow(df2)), ]

#  col1 col2 col3
#1   -1   -2    2
#2    0   -1    0
#3    2    1   -1
#4    3    0    2
#5    4    2    0
#6    1    4    2
```

---

Or another option is using `mapply` without replicating rows

```
mapply("-", df2, df1)
```

This would return a matrix, if you want a dataframe back

```
data.frame(mapply("-", df2, df1))

#  col1 col2 col3
#1   -1   -2    2
#2    0   -1    0
#3    2    1   -1
#4    3    0    2
#5    4    2    0
#6    1    4    2
```

Comment: In Python, I can do this by using following code.  **df2-df1.values[0]**

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
# Creating Datasets
df1 = structure(list(col1 = 2L, col2 = 3L, col3 = 4L), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
df2 = structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L), col2 = c(1L,2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 7L), col3 = c(6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L)), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# Output
data.frame(sapply(names(df1), function(i){df2[[i]] - df1[[i]]}))
#    col1 col2 col3
# 1   -1   -2    2
# 2    0   -1    0
# 3    2    1   -1
# 4    3    0    2
# 5    4    2    0
# 6    1    4    2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use *sweep*:

```
x <- sweep(df2, 2, unlist(df1), "-")

#test if same as output
identical(output, x)
# [1] TRUE
```

Note, it is twice slower than *mapply*:

```
df2big <- data.frame(col1 = runif(100000),
                     col2 = runif(100000),
                     col3 = runif(100000))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mapply = data.frame(mapply("-", df2big, df1)),
  sapply = data.frame(sapply(names(df1), function(i){df2big[[i]] - df1[[i]]})),
  sweep = sweep(df2big, 2, unlist(df1), "-"))
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
# mapply  5.239638  7.645213 11.49182  8.514876  9.345765 60.60949   100
# sapply  5.250756  5.518455 10.94827  8.706027 10.091841 59.09909   100
# sweep  10.572785 13.912167 21.18537 14.985525 16.737820 64.90064   100
```